# how to make dynamic collapsible

Tags: html, laravel, dynamic

I am trying to make a dynamic collapsible accordion which allows a user to repetitively add input into an accordion. But what i am doing is only adding the accordion, the second accordion is being attached to the first one where if i click the second accordion it collapse and show the parent accordion.

I have tried to develop the code based on my logic and yet i am missing some element to increment the accordion id.
[image: Add Group Button is adding the accordion but 2,3,4 if i click will only open and close the parent group which is at the top]

```
@php           
  $groupIndex = 0; 
  $category = [$groupIndex + 1 ]; 
  @endphp

  function add_group()
  {
        let groupHTML = 
               '<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">'
            + '<div class="panel panel-default">'
            +  '<div class="panel-heading"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle pull-right "></span>'
            +    '<h4 class="panel-title">'
            +      '<a id="accordion-toggle.attr("href",  "#" + (++groupIndex))" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">' 
            +       'Group'                                
            +      '</a>'
            +     '</h4>'
            +  '</div>'
            +  '<div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">'
            +    '<div class="panel-body">'
            +            '<div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">'
            +                    '<div class="panel panel-default">'
            +                        '<div class="panel-heading">'
            +                            '<h4 class="panel-title">'
            +                                '<a class="accordion-toggle1" data-collapsed="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThreeOne">'
            +                                   'Category'
            +                                '</a>'
            +                           '</h4>'
            +                        '</div>'
            +                        '<div id="collapseThreeOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">'
            +                            '<div class="panel-body">Panel 3.1</div>'
            +                        '</div>'
            +                    '</div>'
            +                    '<div class="panel panel-default">'
            +                        '<div class="panel-heading">'
            +                            '<h4 class="panel-title">'
            +                                '<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThreeTwo">SubCategory'
            +                                '</a>'
            +                            '</h4>'
            +                        '</div>'
            +                        '<div id="collapseThreeTwo" class="panel-collapse2 collapse">'
            +                            '<div class="panel-body">Panel 3.2</div>'
            +                        '</div>'
            +                   ' </div>'
            +                        '</div>'
            +            '</div>'
            +          '</div>'
            +       '</div>'
            + '</div>'; 
    @php 
    $groupIndex++;
    $category++; 
    @endphp

    $('#group_section').append(groupHTML);
  }

    $(document).on('click', '.glyphicon-remove-circle', function () {
            $(this).parents('.panel').get(0).remove();
            });
```

html :

```
    <div id="group_section" ></div>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-add-panel" onclick="add_group()"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add Group </button>

It is adding the accordion, but my 2nd added accordion can't be clicked because the id is not being incremented
```

Comment: Php only runs the first time the template is rendered. try incrementing with javascript

Comment: incrementing with js is using ++ aite ? i have done that. but never solve the issue

Comment: echo the groupindex inside <div class="panel-group" id="accordion(HERE)">

Comment: I have echo inside the id accordion.. it gives me the same result as previous.

Comment: would be easy to do in Vue though ...